# Hibernate4 update not working - LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, hibernate

```
Employee employee = hibernateTemplate.get(Employee.class, employeeId);
System.out.println(employee.getEmployeeId() + "\t" + employee.getEmployeeName());
employee.setEmailString(newEmail);

hibernateTemplate.update(employee);
```

Hibernate:

```
select
    employee0_.employee_id as employee1_0_0_,
    employee0_.email as email2_0_0_,
    employee0_.employee_name as employee3_0_0_,
    employee0_.gender as gender4_0_0_,
    employee0_.salary as salary5_0_0_ 
from
    employee_details employee0_ 
where
    employee0_.employee_id=?
```

Only `get` is executing and the update query is not executing.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using spring framework check you have applied @transactional. Otherwise you tell complete description which framework you are using.Just check your configuration is proper?

Comment: I started learning spring few days back so i have no idea what @transactional means. Can u please provide some more explanation.

Comment: It is for transaction management you donot need to write code for begin transaction ,end transaction ,commit and roll back.

Comment: My bad i did not declare transaction in configuration file. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an Hibernate or Spring transactionality configuration problem. Probally the changes has made in memory but not move to database.

To force this you can use

```
hibernateTemplate.flush();
```

BUT my advice is you work in the configuration of your system. This solution is a patch.

Comment: tried this, now throwing an exception no transaction in progress.

Comment: Could you add some information abour your Spring/Hiberante configuration and the declaration of your class also?